# Page redirection is not working from BaseController (Codeigniter 4)

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I'm trying to make a separate function **checkUser** insede **BaseController**. But page redirection is not working inside this function. Even inside __construction() function this is not working also. But when I use it in initController or any other controller function, then this is working. How can I solve this problem, please guide me.

**BaseController (In my case AdminBaseController)**
[image]

**This is Dashboard Controller**

[image]

**Showing this error**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the CI4 [documentation](https://codeigniter4.github.io/CodeIgniter4/incoming/controllers.html#constructor), **initController() is called after __construct()**. Then, when you call checkUser(), your response object is still not initialized, thus null.

You could move the code of your __construct() method into the initController() method, in your AdminBaseController.

Comment: Sorry, It's not working.

Comment: Whats is the problem now?

Comment: I need a separate method **checkUser()** in **AdminBaseController**. Where I check login status and user privilege. I don't want to write big lines on every page. Just I want to call this function from **__construct()** of every controller. where I can pass privilege ID. But shows the same error when I redirect the page. I can't pass extra parameters in **initController()**. I can pass that in **__construct()** but not working redirection.